# Problema CORS Laravel + vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api, cors

tengo **dos aplicaciones** una en **laravel** y la otra en **vuejs**.

Las urls son las que me creo por defecto al ejecutar `serve` en cada proyecto:

**Laravel**

```
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

**Vuejs**

```
DONE  Compiled successfully                                                                          


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.0.35:8080/
```

Desde mi frontend con **vuejs** accedo al **backend** con una clase que me he creado de la siguiente manera:

```
class Backend{
    host='http://127.0.0.1:8000/';


    async getAllPersons() {
        let url = `${this.host}person`;
        let data = null;
        try {
            
            data = await fetch(url,{
                method:'get',
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                })
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error API');
            console.log(error);
            data = {error};
        }

        return data;
        
    }

}

export default  Backend;
```

Entonces cuando quiera obtener todas las personas simplemente llamo a:

```
this.$backend.getAllPersons();
```

El problema es que me esta dando errores de CORS, entiendo que es cors y la prevencion de origenes cruzados pero no entiendo porque se esta aplicando en mi caso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El backend funciona perfectamente, lo he estado probando en postman.

---

No se si la solucion es a nivel de backend o frontend, es decir si esta en laravel o vuejs

Comment: Configuraste el `CORS` del lado de tu proyecto laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que habilitar los CORS en tu backend, a partir de laravel 7 el paquete de cors ya viene instalado por defecto es solo agregar la url de tu frontend

```
'allowed_origins' => ['example.com', '*.example.org'],
```

[puedes revisar este post](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/laravel-cors/)